# What class of functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are s.t. every point is a Lebesgue point?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

We define say that a function $f\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb R)$ satisfies property (X) if every point $x\in \mathbb R$ is a Lebesgue point, i.e. $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac 1{2\varepsilon}\int_{x-\varepsilon}^{x+\varepsilon}f(y)\,\mathrm dy=f(x)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Clearly all continuous functions satisfy (X), as do certain discontinuous functions like $\mathbf1_{\{x\ne0\}}\sin(1/x)$ or $(\operatorname{sgn} x)|x|^{-\alpha}$ for $0<\alpha<1$. But are there any positive results we can give about properties *implied* by property (X)?

It would be particularly useful for me to find properties implied by property (X) together with nonnegativity.

Comment: This may or may not be relevant to what you really care about, but you have the definition of "Lebesgue point" wrong. Saying $x$ is a Lebesgue point says that $\frac1{2\epsilon}\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon}|f(y)-f(x)|\,dy\to0$, a strictly stronger condition than what you said.

Comment: Regardless, I doubt that there's much interesting (and not obvious) that can be said about such functions.

Comment: As an aside, what does $\mathbf{1}_{x\neq 0} f(x)$ mean?

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be an indicator function (so the function takes value $0$ at $0$).

Comment: You have to watch braces in TeX ... $\mathbf{1}_{\{x\neq 0\}} f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to post this as a comment, so I put it as an answer instead, although it is not. Your $f$ is a Baire class 1 function, which I guess is a trivial implication of (X). Regarding the set of discontinuity, see for example https://mathoverflow.net/q/32033/32658.
Now, if $f$ is a Baire-1, locally summable function, let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions converging to it pointwise; we have
$$|f(x)-\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{B(x,\epsilon)} f(y)\;dy|\leq |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{B(x,\epsilon)} f_n(y)\;dy|+\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{B(x,\epsilon)} |f_n(y)-f(y)|\;dy$$ from which you could get some (again trivial) sufficient conditions for a Baire-1 function to satisfy (X). These are obvious observations, as David mentioned, if I didn't miss something.